# TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have the following code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

interface SingleParamConstructor<T> {
  new (response: any): T;
  id: T;
}

@Injectable()
export class RestProvider<T> {
  baseUrl:string = "http://localhost:3000";

  constructor(private ctor: SingleParamConstructor<T>, private httpClient : HttpClient) { }

  public getEntities<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(this.baseUrl + '/products')
      .pipe(map(entities => {
        return entities.map((entity) => new this.ctor(entity));
      }))
      .catch((err) => Observable.throw(err));

  }
}
```

When I try the code above I get the `TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'`.

The responsible line is: `return entities.map((entity) => new this.ctor(entity));`

What is it that I'm doing wrong and how can I map over `entities`?

Comment: Try `this.httpClient.get<any[]>(...)` or try `entities.body.map(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not telling angular in the `get`, what type of data you are receiving, so Angular automatically assumes that it is [an anonymous object, as that is what Angular httpclient parses to the data to](https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response). Also something not related, since you are using rxjs 6 -> use `catchError` instead of `.catch`:

```ts
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';

// ...

public getEntities<T>(): Observable<T[]> {
  return this.httpClient
    // note below, now angular knows it's an array!
    .get<T[]>(this.baseUrl + '/products')
    .pipe(
       map(entities => {
        return entities.map((entity) => new this.ctor(entity));
       }),
       catchError((err) => of(err))
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost sure that what you get (`entities`) is an object, which is not iterable.

Change the `pipe(map` to `pipe(tap` and do a console.log to see what you are getting from the server,

```
.pipe(tap(entities => console.log(entities));
```

Then if you need to iterate over an Object's props, do an Object.keys(myObj) which returns an array.

Hope this helps u